# How to generate a MACD of a lower timeframe?

Tags: pine-script

I am attempting to generate a MACD (specifically histogram) of a lower timeframe than the current chart. I'm using Pine Script v5, so I've learned of the 'request.security_lower_tf' function which returns a series. When attempting to use it, I'm able to retrieve the lower timeframe data and print it to a label at least. But when I try using that to then generate a MACD from it, my script fails. What is the proper way to use the lower timeframe data as an input to MACD?

```
// Inputs
lowerTimeframeInput = input.timeframe("15", "Lower Timeframe")
macdFastInput = input(10, "Fast Length", group = "MACD")
macdSlowInput = input(30, "Slow Length", group = "MACD")
macdSignalInput = input(15, "Signal Smoothing", group = "MACD")

// Get shorter timeframe of symbol
lowerTimeframeSymbol  = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, lowerTimeframeInput, close)

// Set MACD
[_, _, macdHistLine] = ta.macd(lowerTimeframeSymbol, macdFastInput, macdSlowInput, macdSignalInput)

plot(macdHistLine, style=plot.style_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

request.security_lower_tf returns an array of values, not a single value
Documentation: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security_lower_tf](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf)

For example, if you're on a 30 minutes chart and you're calling this function, you'll get TWO 15 minutes candle data (because 2 * 15 = 30)

Comment: How can I use one of the two returned values?

Comment: Use the array.get() function